# Can MOVs draw lots of current at low voltage?

Tags: over-voltage-protection, mov

This circuit should open my fuse in case of an intentional overvoltage attack.

(think as someone intentionally plugging 100V to the 24V input)

Thing is I can't afford to have more than 45V to the rest of the circuit.

But this MOV draws just around 5A at that voltage....
This would take ages to open my fuse, I was hoping for at least 3x that.

**Are there MOVs that draw more current at low voltage?**

[image: crowbar-like with Fuse + MOV]

Comment: The strongest/fastest crowbars use SCRs. Use the MOV (or a zener) to trigger the SCR.

Comment: But note that blowing a fuse is an irreversable operation. You use the word "attack" which suggests that you're expecting malicious activity. This scheme still leaves you vulnerable to a "denial of service" attack.

Comment: Thanks! "DOS" is taken care here. But if I were to use an SCR crowbar, does it still make sense to use a TVS before it (in an attepmt to control unintentional voltage spikes) or will the SCR crowbar be faster?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question: yes, there are PLENTY of MOVs which can handle currents MUCH higher than the 5A you mentioned, though you did NOT mention the model number (very important). 
Here are limited search parameters on Digi-Key, for example, where you can see many MOVs which can hopefully serve the purpose: 
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/transient-voltage-suppressors-tvs/varistors-movs/141?s=N4IgjCBcpmBsVQAcAuUQFUB2BLFB5AMwFkBTAQwGcBXAJ1JABoRr0BBJkAWxy3TAAMIAL7MATGAAsCaCFTpseImSp0GzVpBAA1Tl3IAPdJICse3ugDMZ4baA

MOVs can draw a large current spike going from tens to hundreds or even thousands of amperes but for an extremely short amount of time, typically specified in microseconds, 8/20 microseconds being standard, that is 8 microseconds until the current reaches 90% of its peak current rating, 20 microseconds until the current drops back to 50% of MOV's peak rating. 
MOVs are basically made for very brief voltage transients, that's why you will see them blown up or burned out if an overvoltage condition has lasted longer than a few milliseconds - their energy absorption capacity is limited by their size.

As others have suggested, you should use an SCR crowbar circuit, but with a couple of elements to help slow the voltage rise, as below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6X0Ty.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The inductor L1 serves to slow down the inrush current rise when higher voltage is applied. 
The capacitor C1 serves to slow down the voltage rise when higher voltage is applied. 
The R1 limits the zener current to prevent burning the zener diode and the SCR gate. 
The R2 makes sure the SCR doesn't turn on due to leakage currents. 
Any of the component values can be changed, these are merely quick suggestions. 
You could also add a small value (up to 10uF) high-voltage (100V or higher) film capacitor on input to further reduce the voltage spikes.

Answer (score 0):

To make a sensible decision you're going to have to place a limit on what the maximum input current and voltage could be, as well as how quickly that voltage could be ramped up. If that number is too high the MOV and likely the fuse may not provide adequate protection. Fuses have a specified maximum breaking current and voltage. MOVs do not limit very precisely, or with a very steep curve, as you've noted. The fuse may pass hundreds of A before it actually opens (and may continue to arc for some time if the fault current is too high).

TVS diodes are better, and there are always things like crowbars for shunting excessive inputs. The situation with high applied voltage before the crowbar fires may or may not expose your circuitry to excessive voltage depending on how fast you allow the input to be applied.

You could also try putting something in series (depending on what  your requirements are). For example, if your clamp limits the peak input voltage to 100V you might be able to use a series MOSFET to block the input before it exceeds 45V.